# Header file "glade.h" not found : Code::Blocks - Windows 7

Tags: c, windows, glade

I am trying to compile a GUI C program and all the GUI part has been developed in Glade.

## include < glade.h> - Not found

Could someone please tell me from where can I download this header file.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here at sourceforge.net: [Glade/Gtk+ for Windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gladewin32/files/)

Better [here](https://glade.gnome.org/), which seems more to be up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I got the all the header files from the link:

http://gladewin32.sourceforge.net/

Thanks